# boton submit con bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, wordpress

tengo el siguiente código que permite abrir una ventana modal y loguearse a Wordpress, funciona, solo que el código original que descargue de la web, tiene el botón `<SUBMIT>` fuera del `<form></form>` pero esto hace que el botón `<SUBMIT>` no funcione, si lo coloco dentro de las etiquetas  ya funciona, pero el efecto `<footer>` de la ventana emergente se pierde un poco.

***Este código no funciona para loguearse, pero la ventana modal se ve bien.***

```
<button type='button' class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popUpWindow">Login</button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="popUpWindow">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <!-- header -->
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Loguearse</h3>
              </div>
              <!-- body -->
              <div class="modal-header">
                <form class="login-container" name="loginform" id="loginform" role="form" action="../wp-login.php" method="POST">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario"/>
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
                    <!-- footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer"> 
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="submit">
                        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="/social1">
                    </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

***si lo pongo asi funciona el login, pero la estetica se pierde un poco.***
funciona por que el boton está dentro de las etiquetas form.

```
 <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popUpWindow">Login</button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="popUpWindow">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <!-- header -->
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Loguearse</h3>
              </div>
              <!-- body -->
              <div class="modal-header">
                <form class="login-container" name="loginform" id="loginform" role="form" action="../wp-login.php" method="POST">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario"/>
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                  </div>

                  <!-- footer -->
                  <div class="modal-footer"> 
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="submit">
                        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="/social1">
                    </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Como hacer que el botón SUBMIT funcione, aún cuando está fuera del form.

de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Massimo, podrías forzar el submit desde JavaScript al presionar el botón. Algo como `document.getElementById("tuForm").submit();` y luego crear una función para el submit.

Comment: Buenas Massimo, podrías intentar llamar a una función en el evento onclick del botón que recoja los valores del formulario, haces las comprobaciones necesarias y con una peticion ajax envías los datos al servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes abrir el `form` después de `<div class="modal-content">` y cerrar la etiqueta `form` después del `footer` sin problema alguno.

Otra cosa que debes tener en cuenta son las clases que estás usando. En `<!-- body -->` tienes `<div class="modal-header">`

```
<button type='button' class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popUpWindow">Login</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="popUpWindow">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form class="login-container" name="loginform" id="loginform" role="form" action="../wp-login.php" method="POST">
        <!-- header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title">Loguearse</h3>
        </div>
        <!-- body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario"/>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer"> 
          <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="submit">
          <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="/social1">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: El segundo div con class `.modal-header` está cerrando el `form` antes de que lo haga su propia etiqueta `</form>`

Comment: Tienes razón @JheymanMejia ya corregí ese detalle... Lo he usado tal como lo tengo en la respuesta _con la corrección sugerida_ y funciona!

Comment: Perfecto!!, funciona!!, Gracias

Comment: Si te ha servido la respuesta, te invito a aceptarla para que sirva de referencia a futuros visitantes que vengan en busca de un problema similar. De paso, ambos ganamos reputación!

Answer (score 0):

utiliza el atributo Form en el boton

```
<button type='button' class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popUpWindow">Login</button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="popUpWindow">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <!-- header -->
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Loguearse</h3>
              </div>
              <!-- body -->
              <div class="modal-header">
                <form class="login-container" name="loginform" id="loginform" role="form" action="../wp-login.php" method="POST">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario"/>
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
                    <!-- footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer"> 
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" form="loginform" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="submit">
                        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="/social1">
                    </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: interesante, siempre es bueno tener varias opciones. Gracias. Saludos